# How to get multipal post type archive?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i want to get archives of multipal custom post types can u help me guys here is my code which is not working

```
 <?php $args = array(

    'type'            => 'yearly',

    'limit'           => '',

    'format'          => 'custom ', 

    'before'          => '',

    'after'           => '',

    'show_post_count' => false,

    'echo'            => 1,

    'order'           => 'DESC',

    'post_type'     => array('news','update')

);

wp_get_archives( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'    => array('news','update'),
    'post_status'  => 'archive',
    'type'         => 'monthly',
    'echo'         => 0,
    'order'        => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );


// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );?>
            </a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </article>

        <?php

    }

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: this will not show me   'type' => 'yearly' your code will show posts not archives i need something like this 
https://prnt.sc/lk7uye

Comment: pass same argument  you mention in question.Use $query = new WP_Query( $args ) and check.